# How to design list with complexTypes in XSD

Tags: actionscript-3, xsd, schema

I have a problem with converting AS3 classes to XML.
There is a list - **items: Array** with possible classes

```
class ImageVO extends BaseSceneElementVO
class ShapeVO extends BaseSceneElementVO
```

need to convert:

```
<xs:element name="items" type="imageList"/>
```

where:

```
<xs:complexType name="imageList">
<!-- here i'm hesitate-->
    <xs:choice>
        <xs:element name="Image" type="Image" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        <xs:element name="Shape" type="Shape" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="Image">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="BaseSceneElement">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element .../>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="Shape">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="BaseSceneElement">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element .../>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="BaseSceneElement">
        ...
    </xs:complexType>
```

if i will put **ShapeVO** and **ImageVO** in array i will have the next result

```
<items>
      <Image/>
      <Image/>
      <Shape/>
      <Shape/>
</items>
```

i.g. every object converts in **Image** and in **Shape**.
I need to design XSD structure, but i don't know how.

I have tried to make like [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/ws-tip-xsdchoice/index.html) but no sense.
Help me please!

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want an XSD that matches your classes, i.e. a list of polymorphic choices that extend BaseSceneElementVO; and that will match the example XML you gave.

In your XSD (the part where you're hesitate):

```
<xs:choice>
    <xs:element name="Image" type="Image" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    <xs:element name="Shape" type="Shape" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
</xs:choice>
```

This is a **choice of lists**: a list of `<Image>` elements **or** a list of `<Shape>` elements - so instead of a list that mixes them, it will be a list of only `<Image>` or only `<Shape>`. But in order to match your classes, and validate your example XML, you want a **list of choices**, like this:

```
<xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <xs:element name="Image" type="Image" />
    <xs:element name="Shape" type="Shape" />
</xs:choice>
```

To summarise using the notation of expression notations: you have `i*|s*` but you need `(i|s)*`.

BTW: you also could use *substitution groups* but these are less clear, a little rarer, and I understand that not all tools support them.

Comment: I'm using standart Adobe's tools from mx.rpc.xml package, but seems it doesn't support list of choices(

I will try to use Substitution groups instead, but i am a new in this. Could anyone help me?
Thank's in advance.

Comment: @adellantado It's very odd that you say list of choices isn't supported - it's fundamental.  I just checked mx.rpc.xml and the only object-to-xml serialization class is [SimpleXMLEncoder](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/xml/SimpleXMLEncoder.html#](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/xml/SimpleXMLEncoder.html) - and this doesn't use an xml schema at all.  I think it will be helpful if you take a step back and redefine what you want to achieve (and why) in your question - there may be a simpler way to achieve it.

Comment: Most classes inside mx.rpx.xml marked with metadata '[ExcludeClass]', so i copied this package inside my src and comment tags. 
More info you can find [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/966902/how-to-go-from-xsd-schema-to-actionscript-object-flex-at-runtime)

So if i use list of choises, [SchemaMarshaller](http://opensource.adobe.com/svn/opensource/flex/sdk/trunk/frameworks/projects/rpc/src/mx/rpc/xml/SchemaMarshaller.as) throws error - absolutely insane: "String 'myArray' is not a Boolean.".
I have tried to make more experiments but no sense.
Thank's